# centos - Remove penguin logo at startup

Tags: centos

I want to remove penguins logo that is shown in top left corner when my embedded Centos start. After reading a lot about, I'm not sure if I need to recompile kernel, not recompile kernel or what to use to achieve that behaviour. Any ideas about how to remove this penguins? I'm using custom playmouth but this penguins continue being shown when system startup.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872463/how-can-i-disable-the-startup-penguins-and-boot-text-on-linaro-ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt :

```
logo.nologo [FB] Disables display of the built-in Linux logo.
        This may be used to provide more screen space for
        kernel log messages and is useful when debugging
        kernel boot problems.
```

(ps. Where have you been reading a lot about kernel?)

Answer (score 2):

You can do

## make menuconfig

And untick logo option from kernel config. You will never see penguin logo again after you compiled kernel successfully.I can not remember in which part of kernel config. You can check it from kernel config.

Comment: I always enabled penguin logo when I compiled own custom kernel.So I can see a different between default kernel and custom kernel when I booted up own custom kernel.