# How to prevent boot logo for systems deployed using anaconda kickstart?

Tags: kickstart, installer-anaconda

I am looking for a way to prevent the Linux logo from appearing at boot time for a system deployed using Anaconda kickstart.

Based on [centos - Remove penguin logo at startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332198/centos-remove-penguin-logo-at-startup) it seems that I need to add `logo.nologo` kernel parameters.

Still, I don't know how to do this inside the kickstart file.

Related: I am also looking to force it not to use graphics mode, as I never need GUI on these machines (usually VMs, sometimes bare metals)

Answer (score 0):

According to  https://pykickstart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kickstart-docs.html#bootloader :

> --append APPENDLINE
>
> Specifies kernel parameters. The default set of bootloader arguments
>   is “rhgb quiet”. You will get this set of arguments regardless of what
>   parameters you pass to –append, or if you leave out –append entirely.
>   For example:
>
> `bootloader --location=mbr --append="hdd=ide-scsi ide=nodma"`

Answer (score 0):

In order to assure that no logo is displayed and that the default text mode is preserved I had to do modifications in two places:

pxe boot installation menu, adding these kernel options to the `append` line:

```
logo.nologo nomodeset i915.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0
```

And the same params to the kickstart config file used for deployment:

```
 bootloader --location=mbr --append="..."
```

Thanks to @Ipor Sircer forthe last part.